Why does this Artem Chapeye short story seem to imply that Ukrainian mass transit is a fast method of travel?
The short story The Ukraine (by Artem Chapeye, in the collection Love in Defiance of Pain) has the following quote:

Almost every weekend, she and I would get on a train or a bus and head off somewhere. And, in Ukraine, you can get far in the course of a weekend. And make it home, too.

I'm slightly confused about this statement. Why can you notably travel far in Ukraine? (The story refers to busses, trains, and hitchhiking, none of which seem like especially fast methods of travel). Can someone explain this to me?

Haven't read the story yet, alas, but when talking about getting pretty far with his companion, the narrator seems to have in mind something other than geographic distance traveled.

You can read the full story in the New Yorker: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2022/04/04/the-ukraine
